# Angular dynamically create and destroy components from service

Tags: angular

Hi I am creating modal popover dynamically

```
import { 
    Injectable,
    ComponentFactoryResolver,
    EmbeddedViewRef,
    ApplicationRef,
    Injector
} from '@angular/core';


import { ModalWrapComponent } from './../components/modal-wrap/modal-wrap.component';

import { ModalBoxFlatComponent } from './../components/modal-box-flat/modal-box-flat.component';

import { AddHistoryComponent } from './../modals/add-history/add-history.component';


@Injectable()
export class DomService {

    contentCompt: any;
    windowCompt: any;

    constructor(
        private cfr: ComponentFactoryResolver,
        private appRef: ApplicationRef,
        private injector: Injector  
    ) {}

    showModal(objective: String) {
        const contentCmpFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(ModalBoxFlatComponent);
        const windowCmpFactory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(ModalWrapComponent);

        if(objective == 'addHistory'){
            const modalCompt = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(AddHistoryComponent).create(this.injector);
            this.contentCompt = contentCmpFactory.create(this.injector, [[modalCompt.location.nativeElement]]);
        }

        this.windowCompt = windowCmpFactory.create(this.injector, [[this.contentCompt.location.nativeElement]]);

        document.querySelector('body').appendChild(this.windowCompt.location.nativeElement);

        this.appRef.attachView(this.contentCompt.hostView);
        this.appRef.attachView(this.windowCompt.hostView);



      }

      public destroyModal(){
        // destroy the component
        // or detach the view
      }

}
```

I am able to create the component. Now I need to call the destroy method from within the component so when injecting domservice its showing circular dependency error.

So how do I call the destroy method from inside the created component.

Comment: You're just supposed to clear the view container and that will automatically trigger the destroy methods you need to run.  But the way you're doing this makes that not possible.  You'd see much better success using the recommended methods rather than accessing the body like this and attching to the appref

Comment: @bryan60 : View Ref will not be available in the service I think.  Kindly recommend the right way so that I call a single modal component with dynamic content I can pass in.

Comment: @Vega  check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMjTp12VbQ8

Comment: @AbelD you put a component in AppComponent called your "DynamicModalComponent" or similar and then you construct your dynamic modal component in that component and have a view ref there that you are able to access and clear in the recommended fashion.  You use your service as a communication mechanism with that component and your other components.

Comment: @bryan Like you said anyway I need a view reference some how and I need to pass it into the service.

Comment: no you don't, you're not following.  The view reference is always the same, it lives in your DynamicModalComponent, that is where you insert and destroy your modals.  The service only serves as a communciation channel between other components that want to generate a modal and the DynamicModalComponent which does all the component instantiation and destruction, move all the service logic to the component, and make the service only provide simple signals.  You can't and shouldn't pass view references into services. As a rule of thumb, DOM manipulation should NEVER happen at the service level.

Comment: @bryan60 yes now I got the idea.